# how to resolve imports from shared package expo project in a monorepo

Tags: expo, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, expo-yarn-workspaces

I have an import from a shared package of a typescript file inside my `mobile` package and currently using [expo-yarn-workspaces](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-yarn-workspaces);

```
import { ButtonStyles } from "@org/shared/components/button";
```

But then on running `expo start --clear --web` throws me an error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | const ButtonTypes = tuple("outlined", "primary", "danger", "link");

Answer (score 0):

Github issue merged here - https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1080

Due to some reason, we opted out the decision to use react-native itself. So, not tracking myself. Posting if someone finds it relevant for their work.